# Java regex for parsing environment variables (unix, win)

Tags: java, regex

lets say I have String line with my custom environment variables read from file, which is depend on operating system:

*Linux* (must be in quotes, user pass contains " in it):

> **MY_ARGS="-DusePassword=true -Dpassword=pa"ss"**

*Win* (without quotes)

> **MY_ARGS=-DusePassword=true -Dpassword=pa"ss**

*Win* (without quotes, password in the middle)

> **MY_ARGS=-DusePassword=true -Dpassword=pa"ss -Duser=somebody**

I need to get value of -Dpassword into one group and heading and following text into other groups. I'm unable to find correct regex pattern to achieve this. Position of args does not matter, so they may be switched. There may be even more arguments.

Required result is something like this:

- group[1] = MY_ARGS="-DusePassword=true -Dpassword=
- group[2] = pa"ss
- group[3] = " (or empty for windows, or filled with text after
  password value)

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty straightforward.  Strip off `MY_ARGS=`.  Then, if the string starts with a quote, it must end with a quote, and you can strip off both of those as well.

Now, you should be left with:

```
...before-text... -Dpassword=pa"ss" ...after-text...
```

And the regex `-Dpassword=(\S+)` should give you your required password.